# How to update the properties of an item in the artifactory using REST API

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to update the property of an artifact(In my case sample text file)

I tried the API https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateItemProperties

this is what I tried:

> curl -X PATCH -uadmin:password -H '"props":{"ccs_x1_version":
>   "7.7.7.7"}'
>   "http://XXXXXXXXX:8081/artifactory/maven-dev-local/com/test/sbom/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbom-2.0.0-20180704.094719-1.txt"

but was not successful, as command returns nothing, can someone help me in figuring out the right usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the API endpoint for using the UpdateItemProperties. You're also sending the data as malformed JSON as a header rather than data.

You need to add the endpoint: `/api/metadata/` and reformat your data to a proper JSON.

`{
      "props" : {
        "ccs_x1_version": "7.7.7.7"
      }
 }`

According the the link provided:

**Since**: 6.1.0

**Security**: Requires a privileged user (Annotate authorisation required)

**Usage**: PATCH /api/metadata/{repoKey}/{itemPath}?[&recursive=1]

**Produces**: application/json

**Sample Usage:**

`PATCH /api/metadata/libs-release-local/org/acme?[recursive=1]
{
    "props":{
        "newKey": "newValue",
        "existingKey": "modifiedValue",
        "toBeRemovedKey": null
    }
}`

If you update your request to `curl -X PATCH -uadmin:password -d '{"props":{"ccs_x1_version": "7.7.7.7"}}' "http://XXXXXXXXX:8081/artifactory/api/metadata/maven-dev-local/com/test/sbom/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbom-2.0.0-20180704.094719-1.txt"`

This is also a new rest endpoint which is only available with the latest version of artifactory 6.1.0.  If you're running an older version you're going to have to use the previous endpoint ([Set Item Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties)) in the official JFrog Documentation.

This is formatted `curl -X PUT -uadmin:password "http://XXXXXXXXX:8081/artifactory/api/storage/maven-dev-local/com/test/sbom/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbom-2.0.0-20180704.094719-1.txt?properties=ccs_x1_version=7.7.7.7"`

Comment: We need to set content type in headers, the more correct way is:                                                                                                                                        **curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -u admin:password -d '{"props":{"newprop": "wohooo"}}' "http://somedoamin.com:8081/artifactory/api/metadata/maven-dev-local/com/test/sbom/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sbom-2.0.0-20180709.095354-1.txt"**